# Choosing graph types from dropdown

Tags: plot, graph, data-visualization

Say I have certain data. My requirement is that, I should be able to select the type of graphs I want. For example, if I have an array of 1s and 0s, I want to be able to select whether I the no. of 1s and 0s are displayed as a bar graph, or as a percentage in a pie chart. Is there some library that has this capability? If not, is there some way I can go about doing this?

Comment: Hello @user_9, I think that the question is really very broad. Do you have a language of preference? Are you going to display these data in a website, or as an app?

Comment: Hello @user_9 if my answer helped you could you please give me the bounty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have the answer you are looking for. I had same project for my college I used plotly library in python which will allow you to make the thing you want.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/volcano.csv")

# create figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add surface trace
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=df.values.tolist(), colorscale="Viridis"))

# Update plot sizing
fig.update_layout(
    width=800,
    height=900,
    autosize=False,
    margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),
    template="plotly_white",
)

# Update 3D scene options
fig.update_scenes(
    aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7),
    aspectmode="manual"
)

# Add dropdown
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=["type", "surface"],
                    label="3D Surface",
                    method="restyle"
                ),
                dict(
                    args=["type", "heatmap"],
                    label="Heatmap",
                    method="restyle"
                )
            ]),
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.1,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ]
)

# Add annotation
fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        dict(text="Trace type:", showarrow=False,
        x=0, y=1.085, yref="paper", align="left")
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

here is the example code

and it will work as shown in this link.

[this is the output](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/)